# Is there a way to search CosmosDB items by dictionary values?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a method where I am given a string, `name`. I have a CosmosDB container with multiple items. The items are formatted as following.

```
{
   .
   .
   .
   dictParam: {
      "123": "foo",
      "321": "bar"
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Is there a way I can format a query to return the item that has `name` as one of the values in `dictParam`? So if `name` equals "foo", the query would search through all the items in the container, checking the values of each item's `dictParam`, and return the first item that has the given name as one of its dictionary's values.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I would suggest editing your question to show a bit more detail, especially in what you expect to get in return. That said: You may want to consider altering your schema a bit to have your `dictParam` be an array instead, if you can have a variable number of entries. Then, you can have array entries something like `{ itemId: 123, itemValue: "foo"}` - this would greatly facilitate searching (especially using `ARRAY_CONTAINS`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use udf.

UDF:

```
function iteration(data,str){
    for(var key in data){
        if(data[key] == str){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT top 1 c.dictParam FROM c where udf.iteration(c.dictParam,'foo')
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "dictParam": {
            "123": "foo",
            "321": "bar"
        }
    }
]
```

Hope this can help you.

By the way,as David's comment says,array entries will facilitate searching.You just need to try sql like this:

```
SELECT top 1 c.dictParam   FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.dictParam,{"itemValue":"foo"},true)
```

Comment: Got it, thanks for the suggestion for using UDF. However UDFs are only in Javascript right? I'm writing this API in .NET core. Is there anyway I can do this in C#?

Comment: Yes,you are right.About how to create and invoke UDF with sdk,you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#udfs).